# building freetype on centos 5.8 - 64 bit

Tags: php, gd, freetype, bzip

I am trying to build FreeType for GD module of PHP. Well, I was able to built it successfully for 32 bit centos but i am getting an error on x86_64.

Freetype :

```
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ --enable-shared && make && make install
```

Bzip :

```
make && make install PREFIX=/usr/local
```

Error while compiling freetype:

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libbz2.a(bzlib.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>
> /usr/local/lib/libbz2.a: could not read symbols: Bad value collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make: ***
>   [/setups/freetype-2.4.10/objs/libfreetype.la] Error 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by re-compiling bzip with -fPIC. I Edited Makefile. Changed the line `CC=gcc` to `CC=gcc -fPIC`